# access all events from clockwork manager to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, clockwork

Am using [gem clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) for running scheduled jobs. 
I need to access all events defined in clock.rb for manually trigger the clockwork events when it fails.

For that I forked the clockwork gem by adding `attr_reader: events` in `clockwork/manager.rb` file.

clock.rb

```
module Clockwork
  every(10.seconds, 'job1') do
    p Clockwork.manager.events
  end
end
```

By using `Clockwork.manager.events` in clock.rb it returns all events that defined in clock.rb.

mycontroller.rb

```
module Admin
  class MyController < AdminController

    require 'clockwork'

    def index
      @events = Clockwork.manager.events
    end
  end
end
```

But while using it in controller it returns empty value.

How to get all clockwork events in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `development` mode not all application code is loaded during startup, likely the code where you defined your events is not loaded yet.

You can `require` that specific file in your controller, afterwards they should be visible.

In `production` mode all code is loaded during startup so in that mode it should already work.